# How can you get the fullname, path plus filename from ls?

Tags: powershell

I can for example do this:

```
PS C:\Builds\Main\> ls "C:\Builds\Main\Prod\Core\prodXML\prodXML\prodXMLElement.cpp" -Name
```

but then the output is `prodXMLElement.cpp`.

I want to pipe the output of ls to a console program that expects the full file name, including the directory, so I want to get:

```
C:\Builds\Main\Prod\Core\prodXML\prodXML\prodXMLElement.cpp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ls` is an *alias*  for `Get-ChildItem` so you will find plenty of information about this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) (You can also find this information by typing [`Get-Help Get-ChildItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)). To get the whole path, just omit the `-Name` switch. Depending what your pipe target expects, you may have to *select* the `FullName`.

**Example:**

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.cpp' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Comment: I'm dabling about editing your post to add the shorthand notation `gci -filter '*.cpp' | select fullname`. It would show that you can be as verbose or quite terse as you like but it might also start bad habits... I'll let you decide on that :)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I tend to *never* use aliases on SO and my scripts since it makes them harder to read. I do use them on the interactive cmdline ;-)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - Aliases may not exist on any particular system, or may have been redefined, so I'll use the full cmdlet in explanations or scripts to be sure that the correct cmdlet is actually being used. I also don't generally rely on positional parameters, but always use the parameter name, for clarity.

Comment: @JffZeitlin Thanks for adding the link.

Comment: All true, no argument there but newcomers will undoubtly visit SO and might be put off by the length of the commands. Showing shorter alternatives with the necessary warnings next to the preferred way might draw them in sooner *(or teach bad habits)*. Just thinking out loud, this should be meta anyway.

Comment: Thanks, this worked: "Get-ChildItem  C:\Builds\Main\Prod\Core\prodXML\prodXML -Filter 'prodXMLElement.cpp' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName." I tried ls with -FullName before though, but that did not work.